# Form GET removes current URI

Tags: php, html

I have a current URI which filters my search results in the form of (example)

```
search.php?gallery=205&view=listings
```

This query produces a number of results so I also have pagination and additional filters which produce (example)

```
search.php?sortByType=mostWatched&page=1
```

I also have a form

```
<form name="frmFilterResults" id="frmFilterResults" method="get" action="<?php echo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
```

I am having an issue that if I have the first URI above and then click the form filter (submit) button the URI is replaced with the second one when in fact I need the 2 to be joined so essentially if I am on the first URI and click the form filter (submit) or the pagination I get something like

```
search.php?gallery=205&view=listings&sortByType=mostWatched&page=1
```

I had all this working using POST types but because I need the ability to use the browser back button I thought to change it to GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hidden inputs that will keep the GET variables, and send them again when you submit the form.

Example:

```
<input type="hidden" id="gallery" value"<?php if (isset($_GET['gallery'])) echo $_GET['gallery'] ?>" />
```

In this case, the next time you'll submit the form, *gallery* will be passed in the URL.

Comment: Thank you. I didnt even think of that!